# Solving ODE in complex domain with Python (or Matlab)

Tags: python, matlab, numerical-methods

As a test for a more complicated system, I want to solve a differential equation dw/dz = w where the function w = w(z) is complex valued and z = x+iy as usual. The boundary conditions are w = i when z = i. The solution is of course complex and defined on the argand plane. I was hoping to solve this with some standard ODE solvers in python. My method is to first define a grid in the argand plane (lines of constant x and y) and then loop through each grid line and call an ODE solver on each iteration. In the below code I am attempting to integrate my differential equation between 1j and 2j, but the resulting vector of w is just 1j! Can anyone advise me what to do? Thanks

```
    from scipy.integrate import ode
    import numpy as np
    from matplotlib.pylab import *


    def myodeint(func, w0, z):
        w0 = np.array(w0, complex)
        func2 = lambda z, w: func(w, z)   # odeint has these the other way :/
        z0 = z[0]
        solver = ode(func2).set_integrator('zvode').set_initial_value(w0, z0)
        w = [solver.integrate(zp) for zp in z[1:]]
        w.insert(0, w0)
        return np.array(w)

    def func2(w, z, alpha):
        return alpha*w

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        # Set grid size in z plane
        x_max = 3
        x_min = 0
        y_max = 3
        y_min = 0

        # Set grid resolution
        dx = 0.1
        dy = 0.1

        # Number of nodes
        x_nodes = int(np.floor((x_max-x_min)/dx)+1)
        y_nodes = int(np.floor((y_max-y_min)/dy)+1)

        # Create array to store value of w(z) at each node

        ww = np.zeros((y_nodes,x_nodes), complex)

        # Set boundary condition: w = w0 at x = x0, y = y0
        x0 = 0
        y0 = 1
        i0 = (x0-x_min)/dx
        j0 = (y_max-y0)/dy
        w0 = 1j
        ww[j0,i0] = w0


        z0 = 1j

        alpha = 1
        z = np.linspace(z0, z0+1j, 200)
        w = myodeint(lambda w, z: func2(w, z, alpha), [w0, 0, 0], z)
```

Comment: I'm a Matlab person, so I'm not sure if I'm reading the code correctly, but I wonder if an issue could be with `z`. It's a purely imaginary vector. If such a vector is used for `tspan` with one of Matlab's ODE solvers (e.g., `ode45`), an error is thrown: "The entries in tspan must strictly increase or decrease." Does `z` really need to be complex? Are you sure that using an ODE integrator is appropriate rather than [a quadrature method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5965583/use-scipy-integrate-quad-to-integrate-complex-numbers)?

Comment: Thanks for your response. Indeed z needs to be complex as I want to find the value of the complex valued function w(z) at every point on a grid in the argand (complex) plane. Im not sure about quadrature methods, I really dont mind what method is used as long as I get a good approximation for the function w (defined by the differential equation) over a specified 2D grid on the complex plane.