# Integrate with scipy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, complex-numbers

I want to integrate `x**(-2/3)*(x-1)**(1/3)` from 0~1, I had changed variables and use Simpson rule to solve it before,and now I want to try some quicker methods.

my code:

```
x1 = lambda x: x**(-2/3)*(x-1)**(1/3)
integrate.quad(x1,0,1)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scipy/integrate/quadpack.py", line 281, in quad
    retval = _quad(func,a,b,args,full_output,epsabs,epsrel,limit,points)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scipy/integrate/quadpack.py", line 345, in _quad
    return _quadpack._qagse(func,a,b,args,full_output,epsabs,epsrel,limit)
quadpack.error: Supplied function does not return a valid float.
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: Could you, please, show the output of `x1(0)`?

Comment: yeah,it is a singularity.It is ok to integrate just `lambda x: x**(-2/3)`, quad function can deal with the singularities,  but I have no idea with this one.

Comment: Are you sure that your function work right? Because `x**(-2/3)` and `x**(-2./3.)` is different functions.

Comment: @AlexeiShestakov in Python 2 only. In Python 3 they are the same

Comment: @soon Didn't know about it, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though the heading says Integrate with numpy, I suppose you mean scipy.. Your problem is that you have complex numbers in your function. For example, the part `(x-1)**(1/3)` becomes complex for x in [0, 1), but `scipy.integrate.quad` does not handle complex numbers. See e.g. [Use scipy.integrate.quad to integrate complex numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5965583/use-scipy-integrate-quad-to-integrate-complex-numbers) for more information.