# Double Integral of Complex function

Tags: scipy, complex-numbers, numerical-integration

Following the method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5965583/use-scipy-integrate-quad-to-integrate-complex-numbers?newreg=1a5ac2f79e3141dbacd8fd73db52c06d),

Can we do this:
∫∫ (x+y)+i(x+y) dxdy = ∫ ∫(x+y)dx + i∫(x+y)dx dy = ∫∫(x+y)dxdy + i∫∫(x+y)dx dy

Problem is ,I am trying to calculate double integral of complex function in python.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. `scipy.integrate.dblquad` real and imaginary parts separately.