# Scipy quad integral of imaginary numbers

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, quad

I want to calculate integral of implicit function containing imaginary numbers
[image: Implicit function]

where f(iz) is something like:

[image: Definite integral]

and g(ix) is something like:

[image: Internal function]

I want to calculate it numerically. Python `scipy.quad` doesn't calculate integrals of imaginary numbers (explained in Code 1 below). `Quadpy` isn't efficient also, because it passes entire numpy array instead of single values of integral (explained in code 2 below) and thus needs additional manipulation. So I am thinking about dividing integrals like in the way shown below (where Re is real part and Im is imaginary part):

[image: Example of integral]

and expanding above equation:

[image: Expanded equation]

Can I do that?

And here are codes, where I show two ways to approach the problem.

Code 1:

First approach `scipy.quad`. According to:
[Use scipy.integrate.quad to integrate complex numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5965583/use-scipy-integrate-quad-to-integrate-complex-numbers)
I tried dividing into real and imaginary parts and calculating integral values of them separately:

```
from scipy.integrate import quad
import numpy as np
import scipy
from scipy.special import jv
import math
import quadpy

B=8
m=4
M_x = 0.3
M_T = 1
theta=0.3

def f_D(x, z):
    print("f_D:",z)
    return 1*np.exp(1j*x)*z

def phi_0(z):
    print("phi:",z)
    return 2/(z*M_r(z))

def M_r(z):
    print("M_r",z)
    return np.sqrt(z*z)

def psi_D(z):
    print("psi_D",z)
    return quad(f_D, -0.5, 0.5, limit=50, args=(z))[0]

def integral_P_Vm(z):
    print("Calling function, z=",z)
    return M_r(z)**2*np.exp(1j*(phi_0(z)))*jv(m*B, ((m*B*z*np.sin(theta)/(1-M_x*np.cos(theta)))))*2*psi_D(z)

def integral_P_Vm_real(z):
    print("Calling real function, z=",z)
    # return np.real(2*np.exp(1j*(z))*jv(m*B, (B*z))*2)
    return np.real(M_r(z)**2*np.exp(1j*(phi_0(z)))*jv(m*B, ((m*B*z*np.sin(theta)/(1-M_x*np.cos(theta)))))*2*psi_D(z))

def integral_P_Vm_imag(z):
    print("Calling imag function, z=",z)
    # return np.imag(2*np.exp(1j*(z))*jv(m*B, (B*z))*2)
    return np.imag(M_r(z)**2*np.exp(1j*(phi_0(z)))*jv(m*B, ((m*B*z*np.sin(theta)/(1-M_x*np.cos(theta)))))*2*psi_D(z))


Quad_integral = quad(integral_P_Vm, 0, 1, limit=100)
P_Vm_integral_real = quad(integral_P_Vm_real, 0, 1, limit=100)
P_Vm_integral_imag = quad(integral_P_Vm_imag, 0, 1, limit=100)

print("Quad",Quad_integral)
print("Real part:",P_Vm_integral_real)
print("Imaginary part",P_Vm_integral_imag)
```

The output of this approach is:

```
Quad (-5.63500792439988e-12, 1.4665732299181548e-21)
Real part: (-5.63500792439988e-12, 1.4665732299181548e-21)
Imaginary part (9.08758050641791e-12, 3.696603118432144e-22)
```

As you can see, normal quad omits imaginary part and thus I am not sure if integral in `def psi_D(z):` also needs to be divided into imaginary and real parts.

Code 2:

Second approach - `Quadpy.quad` the code is:

```
from scipy.integrate import quad
import numpy as np
import scipy
from scipy.special import jv
import math
import quadpy

B=8
m=4
M_x = 0.3
M_T = 1
theta=0.3

def f_D(x, z):
    print("f_D:",z)
    return 1*np.exp(1j*x)*z

def phi_0(z):
    print("phi:",z)
    return 2/(z*M_r(z))

def M_r(z):
    print("M_r",z)
    return np.sqrt(z*z)

def psi_D(z):
    print("psi_D",z)
    return quad(f_D, -0.5, 0.5, limit=50, args=(z))[0]

def integral_P_Vm(z):
    print("Calling function, z=",z)
    return M_r(z)**2*np.exp(1j*(phi_0(z)))*jv(m*B, ((m*B*z*np.sin(theta)/(1-M_x*np.cos(theta)))))*2*psi_D(z)

Quadpy_integral = quadpy.quad(integral_P_Vm, 0, 1, limit=100)

print("Quadpy",Quadpy_integral)
```

and the error is in line 28:

```
Exception has occurred: TypeError
only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

I tried to overcome this error by iterating numpy array z by modyfing:

```
def psi_D(z):
    print("psi_D",z)
    return quad(f_D, -0.5, 0.5, limit=50, args=(z))[0]
```

into:

```
def psi_D(z):
    print("psi_D",z)
    for e in z:
        print(e)
        return quadpy.quad(f_D, -0.5, 0.5, limit=50, args=(e))[0]
```

But the iteration stops at first element in z array and I have an error:

```
Exception has occurred: TypeError
f_D() argument after * must be an iterable, not numpy.float64
```

I have no idea how to iterate over entire numpy array in this case.

Comment: It's been a long time since I took a complex math class.  Just what does the complex  integral mean?  Same as treating the real and imaginary parts as 2dimensions, in effect a 2d integral on `x` and `y`, or are they more tightly bound?  `np.quad` is a single value integral.  There is a `dblquad`

Comment: did you take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5965583/use-scipy-integrate-quad-to-integrate-complex-numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my interpretation of your integral

[image: integral]

The answer about how to generalize the integral can be extended to double integral (provided by [dblquad](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.dblquad.html#scipy.integrate.dblquad) function).

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import dblquad

def complex_dblquad(func, a, b, g, h, **kwargs):
    def real_func(z, x):
        return np.real(func(z, x))
    def imag_func(z, x):
        return np.imag(func(z, x))
    real_integral = dblquad(real_func, a, b, g, h, **kwargs)
    imag_integral = dblquad(imag_func, a, b, g, h, **kwargs)
    return (real_integral[0] + 1j*imag_integral[0], real_integral[1:], imag_integral[1:])
```

Then you compute your integral as follows

```
complex_dblquad(lambda z,x: np.exp(1j*x*z), 0, 1, 0.3, 0.9)
```

Comment: Thank you! Using your answer, I wrote the code and used following equation:

`complex_integral = complex_dblquad(lambda z,x: np.sqrt(1+z*z)**2*(2/np.sqrt(1+z*z))**2*H_interpolation(x)*np.exp(1j*2/np.sqrt(1+z*z)*x), 0, 1, -0.5, 0.5)`

Is this proper implementation of this set of equations? https://i.stack.imgur.com/8d4VF.png

More details: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4166396/did-i-properly-implement-double-integral-equation-in-dblquad-python-helicoidal