# Solve integral in an annular domain in Python

Tags: python, scipy, integral, numerical-integration, quad

I am trying to solve a function in an annular domain that has a change of phase with respect to the angular direction of the annulus.

My attempt to solve it is the following:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import integrate

def f(x0, y0):
    
    r = np.sqrt(x0**2 + y0**2)
    
    if r >= rIn and r <= rOut:
        theta = np.arctan(y0 / x0)
        R = np.sqrt((x - x0)**2 + (y - y0)**2 + z**2)
        integrand = (np.exp(-1j * (k*R + theta))) / R
        return integrand
    else:
        return 0


# Test

rIn = 0.5
rOut = 1.5
x = 1
y = 1
z = 1
k = 3.66

I = integrate.dblquad(f, -rOut, rOut, lambda x0: -rOut, lambda x0: rOut)
```

My problem is that I don't know how to get rid of the division by zero occuring when I evaluate `theta`.

Any help will be more than appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [numpy.arctan2](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arctan2.html) instead, it will have problems only if both x and y are zero, in which case the angle is undetermined.

Also I see you that your integrand is complex, in this case you will probably have to handle real and imaginary part separately, as done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67719262/12750353).